# column value comparison and fill color change based on the expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am comparing 2 similar tables from different data warehouses and writing a report to highlight the discrepancies based on the differences. I would like to highlight the column values of the 2 fields if they are different. So, I am trying to write the Fill COLOR Expression which can change the color based on the value in the column.

I have tried writing some expressions.

Below are the examples:

I tried :

=IIF(Fields!DB1.Value=”NULL”,”Red” ,”White”) Or 
IIF(Fields!Db2.Value=”NULL”,”Red” ,”White”)  Or IIF(Fields!DB1.Value=Fields!DB2.Value,"NO Color","Red")

--Not Working

=IIF(Fields!DB1_Number.Value<>Fields!DB2_Number.Value,"NO Color","Red")

-- Not Handling NULL

There are no error. It is just that the code is not behaving as per the intention.[image]

Comment: have you tried isnothing?

Comment: Yes. But, it is not working for the NULL.

Comment: Isnothing is equivalent to checking for NULL.. test =isnothing(Fields!DB1.Value) to see if it returns a 1 for null values.. if it does.. then it is working.

Comment: It's not clear what you're intending to get. The first example you gave has the `OR` statements outside the `IIf` functions which means you are just comparing strings and the result would be a boolean, not a color. You'd want to put all the conditions inside one `IIf` statement.

Comment: an alternative approach would be to derive the color in your dataset by doing all the comparisons there (case statements ??)  and assign a color according. Then it is only a matter of using the derived column color as your background color on the report!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the second expression and check for Null before:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DB1_Number.Value) And IsNothing(Fields!DB2_Number.Value), "Red", 
     IIF(Fields!DB1_Number.Value <> Fields!DB2_Number.Value,
         "White",
         "Red")
     )
```

Comment: this should work but I think the colours are the opposite of the OP's intended outcome. Also, it's better to use `Nothing` (no quotes) rather than `"White"` or `"NoColor"`when you want the default background.